# some problem about the subspace of Sobolev space $H^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $E=\{u\in H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbb{R}^{2});\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^{2})  \}$.

1. Show that $E$ is a Hilbert space with following norm
   $$ (u,v)_{E}=(u,v)_{H^{\frac{1}{2}}}+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y},\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \right)_{L^2},\qquad  u,v\in E$$
2. Show that $C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ is dense in $E$.
3. show that if $u\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$, then $\forall y\in \mathbb{R}$
   $$ u(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^{y}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t)dt $$
   Then prove $\forall u\in E$,$ u(\cdot,0)\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Here is my approch:
Since Sobolev space $H^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is a hilbert space, if we have $(u_{m}-u_{n},u_{m}-u_{n})_{H^{1/2}}\to 0$ as $m,n\to \infty$, then we have a $u_{0}\in H^{1/2}$ which imply $ u_{n}\to u_{0}$ in $H^{\frac{1}{2}}$ norm. that is 
$$ \|(1+|y|^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}(\hat{u_{m}}-\hat{u_{n}})\|_{2}\to 0 $$ Now if 
$$ (u_{m}-u_{n},u_{m}-u_{n})_{E}\to 0\qquad m,n\to \infty$$ then $(u_{m}-u_{n},u_{m}-u_{n})_{H^{1/2}}\to 0$ as $m,n\to \infty$. we need to prove that
$\left\|\frac{\partial u_{n}}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial u_{0}}{\partial y}  \right\|_{2}\to 0$, I use the fact 
$$ \left\|\frac{\partial u_{n}}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial u_{0}}{\partial y}  \right\|_{2}=\| 2\pi iy(\hat{u_{n}}-\hat{u_{0}})\|_{2} $$. Then I don't know how to deal with it. Can some one give a complete proof about these problems? Thanks a lot.